# React-native RNFetchBlob: Axios Post request sends string instead of binary data

Tags: javascript, react-native, file-upload, react-native-ios, rn-fetch-blob

I have been implementing upload file functionality into React-native recently and came across an error where I need to post binary file data into Request body.

First of all, I have checked how **Postman** works and I tested this API into postman where I send `Authorization` and `uid` into request headers and `body` will be **Form-Data** with `document` = `binary file`.

See below is `document` key where we are able to select file object in Postman.

[image: Postman request body representation. Document is of type File.]

Now this Postman request succeeds this way and if I check relevant code for **NodeJs-Axios**, it's just as added here.

This code is from Postman intended just for explanation.

```
var axios = require('axios');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');
var data = new FormData();
data.append('document', fs.createReadStream('LOCAL_PATH_TO_FILE/Screenshot 2021-01-28 at 12.26.32 PM.png'));

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: 'API_BASE/addDocument/',
  headers: { 
    'Authorization': 'Firebase_ID_Token', 
    'uid': 'Firebase_User_ID', 
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

As we are not able to use the same function added above for React-native and I have used `react-native-document-picker`, when I pick any file, the object I get is like,

```
{
 
    "size":1173,
    "fileCopyUri":"file:///Users/Local_File_Path.plist",
    "name":"File_Name.plist",
    "uri":"file:///Users/Local_File_Path.plist"
}
```

I need to upload this file (e.g. plist) via API call to `/adDocument` endpoint where this endpoint expects request body as `document: (binary data)`.

So, here is my main function for **addDocument API call** which needs to be corrected to send proper data to API.

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

async uploadFileData (fileData) {
  try {
    console.log("***** uploadFileData parameters =>>>>> ", fileData);

    const mainPath = fileData.uri.replace("file://", "");
    let readStreamData = await RNFetchBlob.fs.readStream(mainPath, 'base64');
    let readFileData = await RNFS.readFile(mainPath);
    let wrapData = RNFetchBlob.wrap(mainPath);
    
    let data = new FormData();
    data.append('document', readStreamData, {'name': fileData.name});
    //data.append('document', new Blob([readFileData]), {'name': fileData.name});
    //data.append('document', readFileData, {'name': fileData.name});
    
    const apiHeader = {
        'Authorization': 'Google_ID_Token',
        'uid': 'Google_User_ID',
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Cache-Control' : 'no-store'
    };

    const res = await axios({ 
      method: 'POST',
      headers: apiHeader,
      data: data,
      baseURL: 'BASE_URL',
      url: '/addDocument/'
    });
  
    console.log("document/addDocument =>>>>> ", res);
    return res;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("xxxxxxx document/addDocument Error =>>>>> ", e);
    return {  error: e  };
  }
}
```

I always receive failure with this function using any of the above mentioned methods, `readStreamData`, `readFileData` or `wrapData`. The reason is, I am never able to pass binary data into `document`.

What I see in request body is like,

[image]

Here, `[object Object]` is a string and not an object and so, my API call throws me error stating, data missing. It always passes string event I use 'Blob()'.

So, I want to know what I am doing wrong here so my request body is not passing binary data. Please send me any pointers on the topic so I can reach to the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was really issue with `React-native debugger` and not the actual implementation issue. As mentioned here => https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/blob/master/docs/network-inspect-of-chrome-devtools.md, the debugger messes around with FormData and whatever being passed into FormData turns as `[object Object]` string due to `uri` property.

I had turned off debugging and tried on both device and simulator, where following code worked as expected. **No need to explicitly convert file into blob.**

```
async simpleFileUpload (fileData) {
  try {
    console.log("***** uploadFileData parameters =>>>>> ", fileData);

    const mainPath = fileData.uri.replace("file://", "");
    const file = {
      uri: mainPath,
      type: fileData.type,
      name: fileData.name || fileData.uri.substr(fileData.uri.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
    };

    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('document', file);
    
    const res = await axios({ 
      method: 'POST',
      headers: this.apiHeaderUpload(),
      data: formData,
      baseURL: 'http://103.53.72.244:9091/api',
      url: '/document/addDocument/'
    });

    console.log("document/addDocument =>>>>> ", res);
    //alert('uploadFileData::Upload Successful >>> ' + JSON.stringify(res));
    return res;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("xxxxxxx document/addDocument Error =>>>>> ", e);
    //alert('uploadFileData::Upload Error >>> ' + JSON.stringify(e));
    return {  error: e  };
  }
}
```

As simple as that :).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what Paresh has said, mine has worked as expected with "file://" prefix. I was migrating from Ionic to React Native. Naturally, the same logic for sending formdata did not apply as in Ionic.

```
const formData = new FormData();
    images.forEach(image => {
      const file = {
        uri: 'file://' + image.path,
        type: 'image/jpg',
        name: image.path.substring(image.path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1),
      };
      formData.append('Files', file);
    });
```

Plus the axios request:

```
const { data } = await axios.postForm<DTOApiResponse<DTOClothe>>(
        `image`,
        form,
        {
          timeout: 10000,
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
        },
      );
```

That is all.